# Sum meta values of checked inputs in wordpress loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum, wordpress, meta

I try to sum values of checked inputs in wordpress loop and I have construction like:

```
<!--wp-loop-->
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php the_title(); ?>" id="i-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<label for="i-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_meta(); ?></label>
<!--wp-loop-->
```

And I have a lot of loops in one page.

```
function updateTextInput() {     
   var allVals2 = [];

   $('.taglist :checked').each(function(y) {

       allVals2.push(<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "price", true); ?>);
   });


   var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < allVals2.length; i++) {
    total += allVals2[i] << 0;
}


   $('#basket2').val(total);


   }
   $(function() {
      $('.taglist input').click(updateTextInput);
      updateTextInput();
});
```

and this is max that I have to do (

my only problem is: this script is not in loop and it's catch only value of last post in category and what's why it doesn't work right((

Comment: You need to get the values from the checkbox elements themselves. php and javascript run in different environments http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Yeah, I've try constructions like $("input:checkbox:checked").val();
with radios - it's ok, but not with checkboxes - "else" doesn't work, count not right.

Comment: probably because you need to set price in markup, can do that in a data attribute and use `data()` to get it. See docs

Comment: looking for..
I've just tried `<?php
$test = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 
 "
  
  SELECT sum(meta_value) 
  FROM $wpdb->postmeta
  WHERE meta_key = 'Цена' AND meta_value = 'checked'
 ", 
 $meta_key
) );
echo $test;
?>` it promises to be working but here I need help with "AND meta_value" - I've never used $wpdb

Comment: suggest you visit the wordpress docs and/or open another question

Comment: ok, in loop: `$('.taglist input').click(function() {
        if (document.getElementById('i-<?php the_ID(); ?>').checked)
 { alert('on') }
 else  { alert('off') }
 });`
else didn't work right, so I can't remove data from array in this case, only add in case if

Comment: `if(this.checked)` ... php doesn't run in browser, forget it even exists in your javascript

Comment: right, sorry( by onclick: `function test() {
        if(this.checked)
 { alert('on'); }
 else  { alert('off'); }
 }` in all cases return "off". and even more: this category have 3 post, if I click first - it return "off" 3 time..